# Where is the mistake in this reasoning?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, inertial-frames

2 identical objects are moving with different constant velocities. Then, in turn  same forces act on them for some period. Both times, the same amount of energy is used to produce those forces. As the forces acted, the objects covered different distances. Hence the works done by the forces are different. So the objects gained different amounts of energy.

So we have a contradiction: The same amounts of energy were tranfered to the objects, but they gained different amounts of energy.

Comment: Why do you think the same amount of energy was used to produce the two forces?

Comment: Need some clarifications. When you say "the same force acts on them for some period" do you actually mean the same physical force? Or is each object acted on by a force of the same magnitude and direction?

Comment: Each object acted on by a force of the same magnitude and direction

Comment: The force acts for the same period of time on each object?

Comment: 2 identical forces (the same magnitude, the same direction) act for the same period

Comment: The source of your contradiction is assuming you can generate the same energy using these forces, since energy is force multiplied by distance. Either you are requiring that the distance traveled be the same for both forces, which requires acting both forces for different amounts of time. Or you require their change in kinetic energy be the same number which still leads to each force acting for different amounts of time.

Comment: @Triatticus Is right. You have contradicting assumptions here

Comment: The set up of your question doesn't make sense.  You can't impose contradictory conditions without getting contradictory results.  And when someone asks for a clarification, you should edit your question with your answer.

Comment: I did some math and get an answer. Take 2kg masses, give v initial of 10 (100 J) and 20 m/s (400Joules) to each mass. Apply a loss of 50Joules to each mass over 10 meters, that equates to 5N force, therefore acceleration is -2.5m/s/s.  And to get the distances to work out to 10 gives time of 1.18 and 0.518 seconds for each mass.  So it works out.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, I see that the 5N forces act for different times in your example, but doesn't the OP specify in a comment above that the identical forces act for the same time? - *"2 identical forces (the same magnitude, the same direction) act for the same period"*

Comment: It's not clear, but in any case it is interesting that it takes a shorter time to exert 5N for the faster mass but the energy expended is the same for both .... something to do with power which is energy per unit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have the same forces (i.e. same amount of Newton), then there are different energies that were transmitted. Or you have the same energy (i.e. same amount of Joule), then you will end up with different forces.

A force is the product of TWO objects, so you can't just say "the same force is acting upon both objects, independently of the objects". If the objects move in different velocities, and you "do the same thing" with them, then you end up with different forces.

Comment: I get a different answer see above or below.

Answer (score 0):

If a force $\mathbf{F}$ acts on object $A$ and on object $B$ for a time $T$, and if the objects have different initial velocities parallel to the force, then the work done on object $A$ by $\mathbf{F}$ is not equal to the work done on object $B$ by $\mathbf{F}$.

If "amount of energy used to produce those forces" means the work done by $\mathbf{F}$, then the contradiction is due to stipulating that the work done by the force on each object is the same while also stipulating that the objects have different initial velocities (which implies the work done by the force on each object is different).

---

> Independently from the objects, in some procedure, a force was
>   produced using some energy . Then that procedure was repeated. As the
>   result, the same force was produced, and the same energy was consumed.

If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that there is some process that produces some linear mechanical power over some time period, and that this same process acts with the same force on two identical objects with different initial velocities.  But this where the contradiction lies.

Assume for simplicity that the process produces $P$ watts of power for $T$ seconds so that the energy 'consumed' is $E = P\cdot T$.

Now, the power associated with a force $\mathbf{F}$ acting on an object with velocity (in the direction of the force) $v$ is $P_F = Fv$.

Since the power associated with the force acting on each object is the same, the force acting on each object can only be the same if $v$ is the same for both objects.

Comment: I didn't mean "amount of energy used to produce those forces" the work done by F.

Comment: Independently from the objects, in some procedure, a force was produced using some energy . Then that procedure was repeated. As the result, the same force was produced, and the same energy was consumed.

Comment: delta v is a x t and E=0.5mv^2.  So if you put a the same energy into both you get  a function of the 4 velocities, initial and final and you can calculate different distances using x=vt+0.5at^2.

Comment: @Cob, I've added to my answer to address your comments.

Comment: I did some math and get an answer. Take 2kg masses, give v initial of 10 (100 J) and 20 m/s (400Joules) to each mass. Apply a loss of 50Joules to each mass over 10 meters, that equates to 5N force, therefore acceleration is -2.5m/s/s. And to get the distances to work out to 10 gives time of 1.18 and 0.518 seconds for each mass. So it works out.

Answer (score 0):

The "amount of energy" needed to produce a given force for a given time depends on the velocity. Mathematically, this is just a fact, proven by the work-energy theorem, but I imagine you want an intuitive understanding.

Suppose that force is exerted by a rope, which wraps around a pulley with a weight on the other end. If the object moves faster, the weight falls further, though the force is the same in both cases. The energy released is proportional to the height loss of the weight, then the energy used does depend on the velocity. (If you don't believe that it takes more energy to lift a weight higher, than can you help me move into my new apartment on the 25th floor?)

Answer (score 0):

I did some math and get an answer. Take 2kg masses, give v initial of 10 (100 J) and 20 m/s (400Joules) to each mass. Apply a loss of 50Joules to each mass over 10 meters, that equates to 5N force, therefore acceleration is -2.5m/s/s. And to get the distances to work out to 10 gives time of 1.18 and 0.518 seconds for each mass. So it works out.

So the question should have said it applies equal forces, over equal distances, for equal amounts of energy.  The time of application is different. So  greater power is required for the faster mass.

Comment: in your conclusion it says "over equal distances", but the question required them to move different distances: "As the forces acted, the objects covered different distances". he implies that both forces will accelerate both objects the same way "for some period of time" (the same period refers to both forces). so then the energy transfer will be different of course

Comment: Thx Phillip, I think he just assumed they would cover different distances but because of the differing velocities.  But I see your point.